# Tracking Dropped Objects using JQuery Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am wondering what the best practice would be for the following project.
I am going to use JQuery to make a drag-and-drop quiz feature. At the end of the quiz, when the submit button is pressed, I want to total the number of correct boxes dropped over correct answers. This means that not all boxes will have been dropped.

I was considering using Javascript classes to instantiate objects (boxes, in this case) and count up through all the objects that had a "droppedTrue" value set to true, for example. Or I guess I could somehow set a property in the javascript of each of the boxes (probably divs) so when the submit button was pressed it would go through all the boxes with a certain marker?

I guess my question boils down to how do I set some type of marker for the divs that have actually been dropped on the correct boxes?

Comment: do it in the drop() event.  If you're using jquery-ui you can make items draggable and droppable.  When instantiating your droppable elemens you just have to bind to the drop() event and run your custom code.

Comment: So - let's so I have 3 boxes with answers and 3 boxes with which to match them with. If I have a constraint on two guesses for each box, where could I store the state of each of these boxes (say, one box has been tried once, another box can't be used any longer because it's been tried twice already?)

Comment: I'll draw you up a jsfiddle with an example.  It won't encompass everything you want to do here but I can get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here it is.  I wasn't sure which scenario you mean for the two guesses restriction (whether on the answer or the question).  I put it on the answer but you should be able to flip it around pretty easily.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fauhq/1/)

Comment: Thank you - the .data function is a very, very useful one so it seems. I am assuming that when an answer is correct, that I will set the 'revert' value to false?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it.  But yeah if you want the answer to stick there you'll have to cancel the revert property.